# Python: Importing Error

Tags: python, python-import

I am doing a mini project in python. My base folder is 'DB'. When imports are between files in this folder they work fine. I have a folder 'GUI' inside my 'DB' folder. When I do imports between files  within this 'GUI' folder it gives error.

So I tried moving the files to the base folder and imports worked fine.

So how can I make my import work fine as well as have those files in 'GUI' folder.

projects/DB/GUI/frame.py:

```
class mygui:
    ...
    ....
```

projects/DB/GUI/wrapper.py:

```
from frame import mygui  # ===>error
```

P.S.This is my first Py project.

Comment: And which error are you getting?

Comment: are you using Django..??..and is your IDE : PyDev / Eclipse..??

Comment: No django.Just a plain python project.I am using APTANA STUDIO(which uses the same 'PyDev' )

Comment: Check your **pythonpath**. You need to include the parent directory of your Project in it..!!..I suppose from **DB.GUI.frame import mygui** would work..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you have a (probably empty) `__init__.py` file in your subdirectory?

(Python needs one to consider the directory as a module package that is importable.)

then try to do

```
from GUI.frame import mygui
```

you also need this step if GUI modules import other GUI modules (given your working directory is the base path).

see [this article](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more details on this.

Comment: Thanks dude.That article was helpful.